# send notification from swift file and recieve in objective c file in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsnotificationcenter, bridging-header

I am trying to send notification from swift file to objective c. My attempt so far:

**ClassA.swift**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let containerDict:[String:AnyObject] =  ["vwConatinerFrameWidth": vwContainer.frame.size.width, "vwConatinerFrameHeight": vwContainer.frame.size.height]

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ContainerFrame", object: self, userInfo: containerDict)

        let classB = ClassB(nibName: "ClassB", bundle: nil)

        classB.willMoveToParentViewController(self)

        self.vwContainer.addSubview(classB.view)

        self.addChildViewController(classB)
        classB.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    }
```

**ClassB.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(containeFrameRecieved:)
                                                 name:@"ContainerFrame"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)containeFrameRecieved:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *theData = [note userInfo];

    if (theData != nil) {

        CGFloat containerFrameWidth = [[theData objectForKey:@"vwConatinerFrameWidth"] floatValue];
        CGFloat containerFrameHeight = [[theData objectForKey:@"vwConatinerFrameHeight"] floatValue];

        NSLog(@"Width:%f and Height: %f",containerFrameWidth,containerFrameHeight);
    }
```

}

**My-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "ClassB.h"
```

But the problem is, the value is not coming to ClassB. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Make sure ClassB adds itself as an observer before ClassA sends the notification.

Comment: @damirstuhec : I did but nothing changed.

Comment: `ClassA`, `ClassB` seems to be ViewController. Are they really "alive" at the same time? What is their life cycle?

Comment: Actually, ClassA viewcontroller adds ClassB viewcontroller as a childviewcontroller in ClassA's viewDidLoad. See the updated question.

Comment: change self with nil in        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ContainerFrame", object: self, userInfo: containerDict)

Comment: @ogres : I did previously, but not working?

Comment: the value is not coming or the notification itself not coming? ig notification is coming, try to print its user info and add it here

Comment: @Johnykutty: Notification is not coming and the method isn't firing.

Comment: see @Iostln's answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an object of `ClassB` AFTER posting the notification. So while the notif is posted, the `ClassB` object doesn't exist. Make sure ClassB's `viewDidLoad:` is called before you post the notification. Only then will `ClassB` be able to listen to the notif and get the value

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought I should post notification before creating the CLassB's object.

Comment: If you do that, at the time the notification is posted, B would not have subscribed to them.

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer for Swift 4.1

```
// Notification name for swift
extension NSNotification.Name {
    static let NotificationName = Notification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationName")
}

// Notification name for Objective-C
@objc public extension NSNotification {
    public static var NotificationName: String {
        return "NotificationName"
    }
}
```

Posting notification in swift file

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.NotificationName, object: nil)
```

Observe in objective-c file

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(selectorName:) name:NSNotification.NotificationName object:nil];
```